# the onclick event gets invoked when i load the page

Tags: javascript, html

Cannot understand why the onclick event gets invoked when i run the file when it should be invoked when i click on the div.

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shoppingcart.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=0;
function swap()//cannot understand why it is running on loading the page
{
  if(count==0)
  {
    document.getElementById('log').style.display='none';
    count++;
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById('log').style.display='block';
   count=0;
   }
}
</script>
<body>
<div onclick="swap()" style="padding-left:30px;height:100px;width:300px;float:left;margin-right:180px"  >
<h1 style="center">LOG IN</h1>
</div>
<div id="log" class="block border goudystout">
Email:<input type="email"/>
Password:<input type="password"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see more code.

Comment: class="block border goudystout", maybe you set **block** class display:block **!important**; so it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess. You are setting `swap()` as your div click handler and not `swap` and hence its executing on page load.

Comment: after changing swap() to swap at onclick , its still doing the same

Comment: it should not unless there is some other code that you have not shown here. make sure you are not testing a cached verion of your file. change method name, put alert or console.log and test.

Comment: actually what you had was correct. it should be swap(). i was guessing a click handler added as part of JavaScript using jQuery or something like that.

Comment: i am not facing the issue that you are facing using your code as it is, at jsBin https://jsbin.com/rexayikiza/edit?html,output. its behaving as expected.

Comment: yeah bet when i load the file the div pops up i want it to pop up when i click login

Answer (score 0):

For one, you've got the **script** section in-between the **body** and the **head** sections, it should be in the **body** section.
This is probably the main reason it is not working as expected.

As per this article: http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javascript.php...

It is legal to have the brackets in the call, you could try putting a semicolon after it, but javascript should be handling the automatic semi-colon insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me

It means you've an issue in your css file, maybe display:block!important; for .block class

```
<div id="log" class="block border goudystout">
```

That's breaking your code

Solve it!

Comment: no the block only specefies the dimensions of the div in my css file